# Correct syntax for SQL join

Tags: sql, join

Please can somebody help me with the correct syntax for this join.

I keep getting the below error:

"The objects "dbo.APRW14_FFA68878_Calls" and "dbo.APRW14_FFA68878_Calls" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them."

Here is my code:

```
select [APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[customer lookup], [dbo].[Customers].[Customer Name]
from [dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls]
join [dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls] on [dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[customer lookup] = [dbo].[Customers].[Customer Name]
```

Can anyone help with the correct syntax?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot reference 2 times the same table without aliasing them... it is ambiguous... for us human readers, and for the RDBMS itself.

Comment: I am relatively new to SQL, please could you help me out with an example how I aliase them? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you were trying to do.

```
select [APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[customer lookup], [dbo].[Customers].[Customer Name]
from [dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls]
join [dbo].[Customers] on [dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[customer lookup] = [dbo].[Customers].[Customer Name]
```

Generally:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Table1
    JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Id = Table2.Table1Id
```